# Drupal nested ajax call not working correctly

Tags: ajax

I got this nested ajax call issue,

```
/**
 * Problems
 * 1). When I click "Add one more" to add more file, I need to click the button
 *     Twice to get one 'Name'/file element available. I click once, no file 
 *     field shows. Click again, one file field will show.
 * 2). When one file field shows, as long as I click 'upload' button of the 'managed_file'
 *     field, this file field will disappear immediately. I upload another file, this
 *     file will be fine. Then another uploaded file will disappear.
 * 3). When I click "submit" to submit the form, all previously disappeared file fields
 *     will show. Because, as you see, the submit function only rebuild the form.
 * 4). If container of multiple file fields are not triggered by ajax, i.e,
 *     $form['test']['names_fieldset'] is not triggered by "select" field, then
 *     tihs "Add one more" function works perfectly.
 *
 * So, why this happens with the ajax triggered container:)?
 */
function agl_jira_new_test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['select'] = array(
    '#title' => 'select',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('man', 'woman')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['select']) ? $form_state['values']['select'] : NULL,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'agl_jira_select_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );
  $form['test']['names_fieldset'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper"></div>',
  );
  if (isset($form_state['values']['select']) && $form_state['values']['select'] == 'man') {
    $form['test']['names_fieldset'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['test']['names_fieldset']['text'] = array(
      '#title' => t('name'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
    );
    $form['test']['names_fieldset']['attachment'] = array(
      '#title' => t('File'),
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="agl-jira-file-attach-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    if (!isset($form_state['num_names'])) {
      $form_state['num_names'] = 1;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
      $form['test']['names_fieldset']['attachment']['name'][$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
      );
    }
    $form['test']['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Add one more'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#submit' => array('agl_jira_example_add_more_add_one'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'agl_jira_example_add_more_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'agl-jira-file-attach-wrapper',
      ),
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

function agl_jira_select_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['test']['names_fieldset'];
}

function agl_jira_new_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //dsm('form has been submitted!');
  // do something.
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function agl_jira_example_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
 // dsm('submitted');
  $form_state['num_names']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function agl_jira_example_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['test']['names_fieldset']['attachment'];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$form['test']['names_fieldset'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper"></div>',
  );` and `$form['test']['names_fieldset'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',` are not so clear to me.. Why there are duplicate names of different form elements? and duplicate divs with same id?

Answer (score 1):

Correct one, just copy and paste it:

```
function agl_jira_new_test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['select'] = array(
    '#title' => 'select',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('man', 'woman')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['select']) ? $form_state['values']['select'] : 'man',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'agl_jira_select_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );
  $form['test']['names_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );
  if (isset($form_state['values']['select']) && $form_state['values']['select'] == 'man') {
    $form['test']['names_fieldset']['text'] = array(
      '#title' => t('name'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
    );
    $form['test']['names_fieldset']['attachment'] = array(
      '#title' => t('File'),
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="agl-jira-file-attach-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    if (!isset($form_state['num_names'])) {
      $form_state['num_names'] = 1;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
      $form['test']['names_fieldset']['attachment'][$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
      );
    }
    $form['test']['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Add one more'),
      '#submit' => array('agl_jira_example_add_more_add_one'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'agl_jira_example_add_more_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'agl-jira-file-attach-wrapper',
      ),
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

function agl_jira_select_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  return $form['test']['names_fieldset'];
}

function agl_jira_example_add_more_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['test']['names_fieldset']['attachment'];
}

function agl_jira_example_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['num_names']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function agl_jira_new_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

removed `$form['test']['names_fieldset'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper"></div>',
  );`, added reference to the form_state in `agl_jira_example_add_more_callback`..

Comment: Thanks @xurshid! Yeah, the two duplicate ids are not necessary. And removing this "'#limit_validation_errors' => array()," will make the "add one more" work. But unfortunately, the 'upload' function is still not working correctly. Every time I click upload, the file will disappear, and then the next upload will be fine..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, answering my own question here. The problem is when I use "limit_validation_error", I need include the first level fields data, i.e.,

```
$form['test']['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Add one more'),
  '#limit_validation_errors' => array('select'),
  '#submit' => array('agl_jira_example_add_more_add_one'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'agl_jira_example_add_more_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'agl-jira-file-attach-wrapper',
  ),
);
```